# When i try to run my cucumber scripts i get an error how to solve it?

Tags: selenium, testing, webdriver, cucumber

I am new to testing . I am trying to learn cucumber automation tool . I got this error when i try to run a script . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B916X.jpg)

Comment: did you even try to google the error message.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387106/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalstateexception-in-package/44387398#44387398

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException in package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387106/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalstateexception-in-package)

Comment: @vipuljain Can you consider to showcase your work please? Thanks

Comment: Follow the error message: download geckodriver and put it in C:\Ruby24-x64\bin.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your gecko driver